# how to replace part of string using regular expression?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
fict={'well':['10B23','10B23','10B23','10B23','10B23','10B23'],
      'tag':['15B22|TestSep_OutletFlow','15B22|TestSep_GasOutletFlow','15B22|TestSep_WellNum','15B22|TestSep_GasPresValve','15B22|TestSep_Temp','WHT']}
df=pd.DataFrame(dict)
df

    well    tag
0   10B23   15B22|TestSep_OutletFlow
1   10B23   15B22|TestSep_GasOutletFlow
2   10B23   15B22|TestSep_WellNum
3   10B23   15B22|TestSep_GasPresValve
4   10B23   15B22|TestSep_Temp
5   10B23   WHT
```

Now I'd like to replace anything before `|` in column of tag to a string like `11A22`, so the dataframe after replace should look like this:

```
well    tag
0   10B23   11A22|TestSep_OutletFlow
1   10B23   11A22|TestSep_GasOutletFlow
2   10B23   11A22|TestSep_WellNum
3   10B23   11A22|TestSep_GasPresValve
4   10B23   11A22|TestSep_Temp
5   10B23   WHT
```

I am thinking to use regular expression with group to replace group by a string, something in my mind look like this

```
df['tag2']=df['tag'].str.replace(r'([a-z0-9]*)|TestSep_[a-z0-9]*','11A22',regex=True)
```

then i got result of

```
well    tag tag2
0   10B23   15B22|TestSep_OutletFlow    11A2211A22B11A2211A22|11A2211A2211A22O11A2211A...
1   10B23   15B22|TestSep_GasOutletFlow 11A2211A22B11A2211A22|11A2211A2211A22G11A2211A...
2   10B23   15B22|TestSep_WellNum   11A2211A22B11A2211A22|11A2211A2211A22W11A2211A...
3   10B23   15B22|TestSep_GasPresValve  11A2211A22B11A2211A22|11A2211A2211A22G11A2211A...
4   10B23   15B22|TestSep_Temp  11A2211A22B11A2211A22|11A2211A2211A22T11A2211A22
5   10B23   WHT 11A22W11A22H11A22T11A22
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(`|`) is a special character in *regex*, you need to escape it.

```
df["tag2"] = df["tag"].str.replace(r"^\w*\|", "11A22|", regex=True)
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

    well                          tag                         tag2
0  10B23     15B22|TestSep_OutletFlow     11A22|TestSep_OutletFlow
1  10B23  15B22|TestSep_GasOutletFlow  11A22|TestSep_GasOutletFlow
2  10B23        15B22|TestSep_WellNum        11A22|TestSep_WellNum
3  10B23   15B22|TestSep_GasPresValve   11A22|TestSep_GasPresValve
4  10B23           15B22|TestSep_Temp           11A22|TestSep_Temp
5  10B23                          WHT                          WHT
```

Comment: oh yeah, it works beautifully! Thanks Timeless, I appreciate your help. so we don't need to use group?

Comment: You're welcome. It is not necessary in this case to capture any group since you just need to replace a word that occurs at (the beginning of the string/column + before a delimiter).

Comment: how to do it if we want to catch a group inside replace? I'd learn it for next time. Thanks

Comment: You might use `df["tag"].str.replace(r"^\w*\|(.*)", r"11A22|\1", regex=True)`. Here, we capture any character found after the delimiter `|` with `(.*)`. Then, we use `"\1"` to place this captured group right after the `11A22|`.

Comment: I see, that is nice. that is really helpful! I definitely learn this trick tonight. Thank you Timeless, I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome roudan.

Comment: Sorry one more question, if I want to capture the group and replace the group by given string? how to do it?

Comment: Use `(…)` to capture in the pattern, and `\1` in the substitution, but ensure to use a raw string `r'\1'`